# Client-side templating for a Single page site

Tags: javascript, templating

Usually in a CMS, there is a template engine where we define "templated html pages", when URL is accessed for a specific page it returned the "templated" rendered page.

However, I want to do single page site and deploy it in CMS, while taking advantage of a template engine that runs on the client-side.

In my current setup, I have a "root" page in which other pages are injected in a specified div like:

```
<body>
   $page.content
</body>
```

Content pages that are injected in this root page are mapped with a URL like: `/home` `/blog` `/etc`

What are the options of implementing such single-page site with templating support? What  I need is a JS Template engine that does not need any server side backend or something...

Comment: Hogan, underscore, jQuery has a few iterations. How do you plan on actuating your strategy to fatten the client? Angular, Backbone, Knockout?

Comment: Haha, as much as i dont want to do this, the site is pretty simple, company profile site and that i don't want to build a whole server backend for this. Its just a single html with #fragments to select pages, I just need that when I do Rest call or something the template page div will render the data

Comment: Why don't you do something like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) then? Honestly, it doesn't sound like you need any template, you just need HTML fragments you can reach out and get.

Comment: don't know about jekyll; looks like it does have lots of stars in github. when you say html fragments that is reachable, you are saying that when I do ajax call to fetch like a json data for a product list, it will transform the html fragment, like <div id="products"> with the json data? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lokking for templet engine then try http://mustache.github.com/ that will helps